# tikzducks page numbering

Tags: page-numbering, tikzducks

How can I have duck-based page numbers, as in the [tikzducks manual](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzducks/tikzducks-doc.pdf) itself? They are adorable, and I would like to have random ducks holding my page numbers.

The manual tells us how to make a signpost duck and obtain a random duck, but how does one create (1) random signpost/pagenumber-holding ducks (2) in the footer?

[image]

Comment: We love you, even if you didn't add an MWE :):):)

Comment: I figured I could get away with it this one time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the end of chapter 3, the "duckumentation" describes how to create a random head decoration or a random accessories without using the `\randuck`:

[image]

(please notice that `\shuffleducks` has to be called each time a new duck shall be created. This is not necessary for the `\randuck`, because there this is done automatically)

The same concept can be used for the page numbers:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 

\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{duckuments}% To create a dummy duckument

\setlength{\footheight}{45pt}
\cfoot{%
    \shuffleducks
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5] 
        \duck[signpost=\scalebox{0.6}{\thepage},\randomhead]
    \end{tikzpicture}
} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

\duckument

\end{document}
```

Tip: the source code of the "duckumentation" is available from http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzducks/tikzducks-doc.tex or https://github.com/samcarter/tikzducks/blob/master/tikzducks-doc.tex in case you'd like to know how do any of the other content.

Comment: You made my day  :D

Comment: @AML Glad to be of service!

Comment: Here a duck, there a duck, everywhere a duck-duck.  Ol' Sam Carter had a farm, EIEIO.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes :) but you forgot to mention the marmots

Comment: ...and on this farm, she had some marmots, EIEIO